# Sending data from front-end to back-end to front-end

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Hi i'm a beginner in using JavaScript i have this html page with JavaScript codes that receives data from the server and display it on this current page, what i'm trying to do is use that data and sending it to another PHP page for my SQL query to get back results.

```
<script>
    var json = sessionStorage.xhr;
    var object = JSON.parse(json);
    var hard =  object["red-fruits"];
    var string = JSON.stringify (hard);
    var stringData = encodeURIComponent(string);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/web/main.php",
        data: {"dataA" : stringData}, 
        cache: false,
            success: function(){
                console.log("OK");
            }
    });
    var user = sessionStorage.getItem('impData');
    console.log(user);
</script>
```

This is my PHP page codes, what i'm doing here is getting the data "dataA" from that html page and sending it to this PHP page for the SQL query and getting the results which is the "$haha" array and using JavaScript session function to send it back to the HTML page. But my console only shows "null" can anyone tell me if i'm doing anything wrong or have any suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","") or 
die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
    if (isset($_POST['dataA'])) {
        echo $name = $_POST['dataA'];
    }
    else {
        echo "Error";
    }

$string = str_replace("]", "", str_replace("[", "", str_replace('"','',$falcon)));
$array = explode(',', $string);
$array2= implode("', '",$array);

$sql = // "SQL query"
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . 
mysqli_error($connection));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $haha[] =  $row['row_name'];
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tills = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $haha) . '"]' ?>;
    console.log (tills);
    sessionStorage.setItem('impData', tills);
</script>
```

Comment: Don't mix PHP and JavaScript. Use hidden inputs to pass data from Php to JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are now mixing ajax and session data on a strange way. The session data used by your javascript will not be updated by the php-script till you refresh your page. The correct way to handle data is in the "success" function:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/web/main.php",
        data: {"dataA" : stringData},
        dataType : "json",
        cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
    });
```

and in you PHP output the data you want to send to the browser as a json string:

```
echo json_encode($your_object);
```

Comment: So i only can send back a json string back to the html page? but how do i send it back to the html page without using sessions?

Comment: You don't need sessions to send data back. The page you request returns a json-string. Your ajax call does 2 things: it request a page and it recieves the answer. The request is a POST to "http://localhost/web/main.php" width data "dataA" and it recieves the answer of your php page in "data".

Comment: wait then how do i access the answer i got from the php page?

Comment: Inside $.ajax() you see the function  success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
The argument data contains all data recieved from the page. See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Oh yeah man i got it already thanks man really appreciate it.